# Using a DLL library in C#

Tags: c#, dll, event-handling

I have a DLL library given to me as homework. I was being told the DLL has the capability of raising events. And I will need to be able to handle those events. I am coding in C#.

Can any one please point me to any tutorials online that will serve the purpose.

Atm, all the google results I get is - *how to make a DLL* or *how to use C++ dll in C#;* they are not helping me to serve the purpose.

Can anyone help?

Yes, I know how to add a reference and can connect this to my project.

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+handle+events+in+c%23&hl=en

Comment: Is the .dll a .NET .dll?

Comment: If the dll is a .NET assembly, you can just add a reference to it in your project. Are you using Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Yes. It is a .NET dll and i am using VS 2010 ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know how to add a reference, all you need is to add the reference to your class with "using [Class Namespace]" and add an event to your event handler.

This link may help you with this part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the project by right-click on the reference-folder in your project. Navigate to the dll and add it. Now you can use it like a project which is in your solution.